# JWT.IO signing error validating bearer from identity server

Tags: oauth, jwt, owin, identity, bearer-token

I have set-up an identity server 3 that serves bearer tokens. I then consume that JWT bearer in my api. All is working fine. However, i cannot seem to validate a token in jwt.io debugger. I paste in the valid base64 bearer into the debugger then try and verify the signature by pasting in the contents of the "x5c" from the idserver/.well-known/jwks into the verify signature. this says invalid. what am i doing wrong? owin works fine with app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions()

Comment: so it turns out i need it in pem format which i managed to create from the json key via this site. https://8gwifi.org/jwkconvertfunctions.jsp. however, what's the difference in formats? how do i get from the jwk base64 or base64url encoded into what exactly? what is this x5c format exactly? and what do i need to do to make it a pem format?

Comment: ok i'm still confused. i can put whatever i want into the pem creator and it comes up verified. what's the science in this jwt.io signature verification? i just don't understand it.